# SQL QUERY MERGE TWO ROW DATA

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, merge

Suppose My Database is like this :

```
MemberName  MemberID   ResultsEligibilityID
Thuso         2              1
Thuso         2              1
Maubane       3              2
Maubane       3              1
CDeveloper    5              2
CDeveloper    5              2
```

Now is it possible to write a query to display (The Below output) based on this:

if both ResultsEligibilityID for a single Member is 1 then Eligibile,
 Otherwise Non-Eligible.

**OUTPUT**

```
MemberName  MemberID  ResultsEligibilityID  Results
Thuso        2              1             Eligible
Maubane      3              2             Non-Eligible
CDeveloper   5              2             Non-Eligible
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I would group by using MAX eligibility and a CASE statement for the Results column. `CASE MAX(EligibilityID)=1 then 'Eligible' Else 'Non' End`

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
select 
    MemberName,
    MemberID, 
    MAX(ResultsEligibilityID) ResultsEligibilityID ,
    (case when sum(case when ResultsEligibilityID=1 then 1 else 0 end)= COUNT(*) 
    then 'Eligible' else 'Non-Eligible' end) Results
From 
    YourTable
group by MemberName,MemberID
```

Comment: Why take a sum, if max>1 then not eligible?

Comment: great stuff :-) Thanks a lot Daniel and Techdo